# Customising Product Specification in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, raphael

I work for a window manufacturing company and would like to add the functionality within the website for customers to be able to customise a product online with a visual representation when adding parts to the order.

So my question really is when parts are selected is it possible to build an SVG image via ajax or maybe Raphael?

The parts would be:

1. width
2. height
3. color
4. glass type
5. grid on outside of glass and so on

thanks in advace

Comment: Possible? Yes, absolutely. Not simple though. You may want to edit your question to ask something more specific than "is this possible".

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with carefully crafted images. You can easily grow / shrink an image, hide/display an image, and overlay them (keep transparency) all with javascript on the client.

I would not do it with AJAX, instead I'd just load all the images and display, hide or overlay as needed (assuming the number of options are within reason).